# Come si dice speech delay

Tags: word-usage, phrase-request, single-words

Come si dice "speech delay" in italiano (che penso sia quando uno fa delle pause involontarie mentre parla)?

Comment: Ti riferisci a questo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_delay ?

Answer (score 2):

L'espressione ***speech delay*** viene tradotta in italiano con ***[ritardo (o disturbo) del linguaggio](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ritardo_semplice_di_linguaggio)*** quando le cause sono neurolopsichiche, cioè

> Il ritardo semplice di linguaggio è l'assenza o il ritardo di
>   acquisizione della verbalità espressiva in termini globali o in uno
>   degli aspetti parziali fonematici, lessicali e/o morfosintattici

Quindi si riferisce ad una patologia per cui la persona (o di solito un bambino) comincia a parlare tardi rispetto alla media. L'evoluzione è solitamente positiva ma i soggetti che ne hanno sofferto possono talvolta fare pause involontarie specie quando intrattengono un discorso.

Come fatto correttamente notare da @DaG, quando le cause sono meccaniche si potrebbe tradurre con **alalia** oppure **afemia**, quando c'è un ritardo nello sviluppo o nell'uso dei meccanismi per la produzione orale.

Per contro ci sono invece le pause volontarie, dette ***pause ad effetto***, che fanno parte dell'arte oratoria e delle tecniche a supporto della recitazione.

Comment: Io non so niente dell'argomento, ma – se è su questo la domanda dell'OP – vedo che la [voce della Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_delay) sottolinea che *speech* è distinto da *language* e si riferisce alla sola fonazione. Sai per caso se esiste un termine più specifico di “ritardo del linguaggio”?

Answer (score 2):

Abarisone's answer is fully correct when referring to an individual's difficulties when speaking.

From your question, you seem to be unsure of the context: if you are referring to a technical delay in telecommunications (such as the time that passes between when a word is uttered in a phone receiver and when it's heard on the phone at the other hand), then the correct term is "Latenza" ("Latency" in English).